# Change paper size to match TikZ picture dimension

Tags: tikz-pgf

I do not want to use standalone since I want to add some text above of the tikzpicture.
So I try to use article and adjust the margin to fit my tikzpicture. In this example, the tikzpicture is 6cm width, so I want to adjust the pager width to 6cm and margin to 0.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[pass,
    paperwidth=6cm,paperheight=12cm,
    margin=0cm,
    ]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,fit,backgrounds,intersections}
\begin{document}
    $2\sqrt{r1*r2} + 2\sqrt{r1(r2+r3-r1)}$\\
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{>=latex}
    \newcommand{\ann}[5][] {
        \draw[|<->|,line width=0.5pt,red,#1] ([yshift=#2]#3) -- node[above] {#5} ([yshift=#2]#4); 
    }
    \newcounter{debug}\setcounter{debug}{1} %debug code: 1-debug,0-release
    [background rectangle/.style={fill=olive!30}, show background rectangle]
\coordinate (O1) at (0,0);
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\path[name path=C1] (O1) circle (5);
\path[name path=L1] (-1,0)--(-1,5);
\path [name intersections={of= L1 and C1,by=O2}];

\path[name path=C2] (O2) circle (3.5);
\path (O2) --++(2.5,0) coordinate (Q2);
\path[name path=L2] (Q2)--++(0,4.5);
\path [name intersections={of= L2 and C2,by=O3}];
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

\path (O1) --++(-180:3) coordinate (P1);
\path (O2) --++(-180:2) coordinate (P2);
\path (O3) --++(0:1.5) coordinate (P3);
\coordinate (P7) at (O1 |- O2);
\coordinate (P8) at (O2 -| O3);
\ann[]{0}{P1}{O1}{r1};
\ann[]{0}{P2}{O2}{r2};
\ann[]{0}{P3}{O3}{r3};
\node[draw,circle,minimum size=6cm,inner sep=0] (Q1) at (O1) {};
\node[draw,circle,minimum size=4cm,inner sep=0] (Q2) at (O2) {};
\node[draw,circle,minimum size=3cm,inner sep=0] (Q3) at (O3) {};
\node[draw,fit=(Q1)(O2)(Q3),inner sep=0] (Q4) {};
\foreach \i in {O1,O2,O3} {
    \fill[shift=(\i),red!50] (0,0) circle(2pt) node[below,shift=(\i)] {\i};
}
\ifnum\value{debug}=1 %debug code
\draw[red!50] (O1) -- (O2) -- (O3)
    (O1) |- (O2) (O2) -| (O3)
    ;

\foreach \i in {P1,P2,P3,P7,P8} {
    \fill[shift=(\i),red!50] (0,0) circle(2pt) node[below,shift=(\i)] {\i};
}
\draw[] ([xshift=-2mm]P7) |- ([yshift=-2mm]P7);
\draw[] ([xshift=-2mm]P8) |- ([yshift=2mm]P8);
\fi
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But above still not change my paper width!

[image]

Comment: You could add the text in form of a node. Then you could use the `standalone` class. And at any rate I would suggest to add the debug stuff with the `overlay` option such that it does not affect the bounding box.

Comment: @marmot Thanks, what's the different between pgfinterruptboundingbox and scope overly option?

Comment: Nothing AFAIK at the level of Ti*k*Z. However, `pgfinterruptboundingbox` is a pgf environment, and can hence also be used at the pgf level. My comment concerned the `F1` label and so on, which are outside the `pgfinterruptboundingbox` and can influence the bounding box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Geometry package documentation](http://mirror.iopb.res.in/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) says:

> `pass` disables all of the geometry options and calculations except `verbose`
>   and `showframe`.  It is order-independent and can be used for checking
>   out the page layout of the documentclass, other packages and manual
>   settings without `geometry`.

Removing the `pass` option in `geometry` gives:

[image]

I have adjusted the height and width slightly.

```
\usepackage[
    paperwidth=6.5cm,paperheight=12.5cm,
    margin=0cm,
    ]{geometry}
```

The complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[
    paperwidth=6.5cm,paperheight=12.5cm,
    margin=0cm,
    ]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,fit,backgrounds,intersections}
\begin{document}
    $2\sqrt{r1*r2} + 2\sqrt{r1(r2+r3-r1)}$\\
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{>=latex}
    \newcommand{\ann}[5][] {
        \draw[|<->|,line width=0.5pt,red,#1] ([yshift=#2]#3) -- node[above] {#5} ([yshift=#2]#4); 
    }
    \newcounter{debug}\setcounter{debug}{1} %debug code: 1-debug,0-release
    [background rectangle/.style={fill=olive!30}, show background rectangle]
\coordinate (O1) at (0,0);
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\path[name path=C1] (O1) circle (5);
\path[name path=L1] (-1,0)--(-1,5);
\path [name intersections={of= L1 and C1,by=O2}];

\path[name path=C2] (O2) circle (3.5);
\path (O2) --++(2.5,0) coordinate (Q2);
\path[name path=L2] (Q2)--++(0,4.5);
\path [name intersections={of= L2 and C2,by=O3}];
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

\path (O1) --++(-180:3) coordinate (P1);
\path (O2) --++(-180:2) coordinate (P2);
\path (O3) --++(0:1.5) coordinate (P3);
\coordinate (P7) at (O1 |- O2);
\coordinate (P8) at (O2 -| O3);
\ann[]{0}{P1}{O1}{r1};
\ann[]{0}{P2}{O2}{r2};
\ann[]{0}{P3}{O3}{r3};
\node[draw,circle,minimum size=6cm,inner sep=0] (Q1) at (O1) {};
\node[draw,circle,minimum size=4cm,inner sep=0] (Q2) at (O2) {};
\node[draw,circle,minimum size=3cm,inner sep=0] (Q3) at (O3) {};
\node[draw,fit=(Q1)(O2)(Q3),inner sep=0] (Q4) {};
\foreach \i in {O1,O2,O3} {
    \fill[shift=(\i),red!50] (0,0) circle(2pt) node[below,shift=(\i)] {\i};
}
\ifnum\value{debug}=1 %debug code
\draw[red!50] (O1) -- (O2) -- (O3)
    (O1) |- (O2) (O2) -| (O3)
    ;

\foreach \i in {P1,P2,P3,P7,P8} {
    \fill[shift=(\i),red!50] (0,0) circle(2pt) node[below,shift=(\i)] {\i};
}
\draw[] ([xshift=-2mm]P7) |- ([yshift=-2mm]P7);
\draw[] ([xshift=-2mm]P8) |- ([yshift=2mm]P8);
\fi
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks, one more question: the margin is 0 but why the left side still some space there?

Comment: @lucky1928 I think it's because of P1 and P2.

Comment: Exactly! after move it to right, it's perfect now! thanks again!

Comment: @lucky1928 --- a hint: if you surround your "debug" code with `\begin{scope}[overlay]  ... \end{scope}` it will not affect the bounding box, i.e., the size of the final image.